# how to call multiple sql stored procedure in a single php page

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call two sql stored procedure in a same page
What I've tried is

```
                  mysqli_query($con,"DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS count_nodes_all_1 "); 
                  mysqli_query($con,"CREATE PROCEDURE count_nodes_all_1()
                               BEGIN
                                  CALL count_nodes_left_1('id-1',750);
                                  CALL count_nodes_right_1('id-2',750);
                                END"); 

                          $qry = "CALL count_nodes_all_1";                     

   if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $qry)) 
                  {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                    {
                          
                          
                          
                             $total_left_1 = $row['total_left_1'];
                             $total_right_1 = $row['total_right_1'];
                          
?>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo number_format($total_left_1); ?></th>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo number_format($total_right_1); ?></th>
```

Here `$total_left_1 = $row['total_left_1'];` is the output of 1st procedure and `$total_right_1 = $row['total_right_1'];` is the output of 2nd procedure
Now, the problem is I'm getting output for `<?php echo number_format($total_left_1); ?>`  and can't get output for `<?php echo number_format($total_right_1); ?>` It simply shows `Notice: Undefined index: total_right_1 in G:\XampNew\htdocs`
Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

you need to use mysqli_fetch_array twice

Comment: As I am a beginner I can't understand. Please elaborate how to use `mysqli_fetch_array` twice